# error while sending email in Java using Apache Commons email libs

Tags: java, authentication, apache-commons-email

I was trying to use Apache Commons library to send email. But it gives me an error saying

> "the type of setAuthenticator(Authenticator) is erroneous" in email.setAuthenticator function.

Here is my code. I am not sure why I get this error.

```
public static void sendSimpleMail() throws Exception {
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("me@gmail.com","my gmail password"));
    email.setDebug(false);
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setFrom("me@gmail.com");
    email.setSubject("Hi");
    email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
    email.addTo("you@gmail.com");
    email.setTLS(true);
    email.send();
    System.out.println("Mail sent!");
}
```

Comment: You are getting the error on the line `email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("me@gmail.com","my gmail password"));
    email.setDebug(false);`, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in sending email using commons-email-1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062549/error-in-sending-email-using-commons-email-1-3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a different method for the authentication data which receives username and password directly, then the Authenticator will be handled internally by commons-email:

```
email.setAuthentication("me@gmail.com","my gmail password")
```